# How to import matplotlib into Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, matplotlib

I've got Python Tools installed for Visual Studio, and I'm wondering how I can import the matplotlib library into it?
I'm kind of new at this so I will be needing a detailed explanation: what do download, where to download it from and how to install it.
Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html

Comment: There's really nothing to describe. I've already checked the link you gave me but I cannot find anything regarding Visual Studio. 
The question remains: How do I make matplotlib available in Visual Studio?

Comment: Figured out how to import a package, but now I'm getting an error when I try to import matplotlib: 
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27